# Java Instantiate a class at run time with String[] stringArray parameters

Tags: java, reflection

I am having trouble in getting the concrete implementation of the class at the runtime.
I get the name of class `className` at run time and I want to initialize it with the constructor which takes in a String array. I have the following

```
stringArray = new String[]{"abc", "def"};
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<MyCustomInterface> constructor = null;
MyCustomInterface myCustomObject = null;
constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String[].class);  // Gives constructor which takes in String[] I assume
myCustomObject =  constructor.newInstance(stringArray);   // I am providing the same here
```

In my Implementation Of Custom Interface I have

```
public class MyClass implements MyCustomInterface{
    public MyClass(String args[]) throws Exception{
        //My custom constructor
    }
}
```

But I still get an exception saying, `wrong number of arguments`, even though I am passing a string array. I am confused as to how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Array types in Java are covariant. This means that `Object[] objectArray = stringArray;` is a perfectly valid statement.

When you call `constructor.newInstance`, your `stringArray` is being casted to `Object[]`, and you are trying to invoke the constructor with two, separate `String` arguments.

You either need to explicitly wrap your `stringArray` in an `Object[]` or cast it to `Object` and let the JVM automagically wrap it in an `Object[]` for you:

```
constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { stringArray });
```

or

```
constructor.newInstance((Object) stringArray);
```

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks. But I did not understand as to Object[] and String[] are same? Does `newInstance` always expect an `Object`?

Comment: No, you have to cast it back to String[] in your constructor.

Comment: @Anoop `newInstance` expects an `Object[]`. It's not that `Object[]` and `String[]` are the same, but they have a relationship similar to `String[] extends Object[]`.

Comment: That clarified a lot of things. Thanks . .